# counting child tags inside the parent tag

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I have a parents div pag and a multiple child Div tags. I want to count the number of child div inside parent div. Is it possible through JSoup? Below is the code to best explain.

```
<div class="pagination">
<div class="label">Page: </div>
<div class="button selected" onclick="$('.page-position', $(this).closest('form')).attr('value', $(this).html()); $(this).closest('form').submit();">1</div>
<div class="button " onclick="$('.page-position', $(this).closest('form')).attr('value', $(this).html()); $(this).closest('form').submit();">2</div>
<div class="button " onclick="$('.page-position', $(this).closest('form')).attr('value', $(this).html()); $(this).closest('form').submit();">3</div>
<div class="button" onclick="$('.page-position', $(this).closest('form')).attr('value', 2);$(this).closest('form').submit();">Next</div>
</div>
```

I want to count the total number of pages excluding the Next button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the document per Jsoup:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);
```

Or:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://url").get();
```

Then select:

```
Elements els = doc.select("div.pagination div").not(":contains(Next)").not(":contains(Page)");
```

Or via regex:

```
Elements els = doc.select("div.pagination div:matches(\\d+)");
```

Get the size:

```
els.size();
```

Answer (score -2):

I would do it with jquery:

```
alert ($('.pagination div').not($("div:contains('Next')")).length);
```